# How do I use my .so library in my Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: c++, c, xamarin, xamarin.android, dynamic-library

Hey I have a method called timestwo written in c++ in my libtest.so library.
Now I need to call this method in my main (Xamarin.Android) Project accelerometer2.

Unfortunately there are just few samples and instructions how to do that from scratch. Most of them are either Xamarin.Forms examples or java/objective c libraries. I have included my source file test.cpp and my header file test.h in a c++ project. But as you can see I still cannot call my function in my main activity.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, ISensorEventListener
    {
        static readonly object _syncLock = new Object();
        static System.loadLibrary("libtest");

        double anothervalue = 1.0;
        double value = timestwo(anothervalue);
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

double timestwo(double x){
    return x*2;
}
```

test.h:

```
extern "C" double timestwo(double x);
```

[image: Here you can see my errors]

[How] Do I need to give a reference on my Main Activity ? Or what do I miss?

UPDATE:

[image]

Does this file belong to the c# project or to my c++ project?

```
internal static class Wrapper
    {
        [DllImport("libtest.so", EntryPoint = "timestwo")]   //,(EntryPoint = "timestwo")
        internal static extern double timestwo(double x);
    }
```

I have changed my wrapper now, but my MainActivity still gives me this error:
Error IDE1007 The name 'System.loadLibrary'does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Via `DllImport` statements and extern methods : https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: I have added a wrapper class now, I hope it is correct.

Comment: FYI: Your `C` extern has a double parameter but your C# extern wrapper does not... (Also please do not use images for code, add the formatted code directly into your question as images are not indexable/searchable, can not be cut/pasted, show up poorly on the SO mobile app, etc...

Comment: In C# ,Using like this: `[DllImport ("test", EntryPoint = "Java_com_example_SanAngeles_DemoRenderer_nativeInit")]
  private static extern void nativeInit (IntPtr jnienv);`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries